# The upper bound of the ratio of two real functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider two real functions $f(k): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ and $g(k): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of non-negative integers and $\mathbb{R}_+$ denotes the set of positive real numbers. Suppose $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, does there exist a $\lambda < 1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(k)}{g(k)} \leq \lambda, ~ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}~?
\end{equation}
By the way, suppose $f(k) = 1 - \frac{a^k}{2}$ and $g(k) = 1 - \frac{a^k}{4}$ with $0 < a < 1$, can we claim that $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Obvisouly $\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} g(k) - f(k) = 0$, but $g(k) - f(k) = \frac{a^k}{4} > 0$ for all finite $k$.

###

Gary gave a nice example for my initial question. So what if $g(k)$ and $f(k)$ are both finite for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Will this lead to the existence of such a $\lambda$?

Comment: Let $f(k)=k$ and $g(k)=k+1$. Then $$
\frac{{f(k)}}{{g(k)}} = 1 - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}.
$$ Is there a $\lambda<1$ such that $1 - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}\leq \lambda$ for all $k$? Do you know about the Archimedean property?

Comment: Good example! Here comes my another concern, what if $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ are both finite for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Will this assumtion lead to the existence of such a $\lambda$?

Comment: @Marshall: I think perhaps you are misusing the word _finite_. Do you mean _bounded_? That means that there are integers $M$ and $N$ such that $f(k)\le M$ and $g(k)\le N$ for all $n$. And if $f$ and $g$ are bounded, then yes, there must exist such a $\lambda$, namely $(N-1)/N$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes. I mean they are bounded. $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ are real numbers, so $(N-1)/N$ may not be the $\lambda$.

Comment: @Marshall: Sorry, my bad. I got the idea that $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ were integers. But if they are real numbers, then no, such a $\lambda$ need not exist. Take for example $f(k)=1-\frac{1}{k+1}$, and $g(k)=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for you example. Now I know that there does not exist such a $\lambda$. But what if $g(k)$ and $f(k)$ are both bounded for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Will this produce such a $\lambda$?

Comment: @TonyK But $f(k) = g(k)$ when $k$ approaches $+\infty$, it violates $f(k) < g(k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Marshall: no it doesn't. $1-\frac{1}{k+1}<1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Marshall TokyK is correct. Can you give me a specific natural number $k$ for which $f(k)=g(k)$ if $f(k)=1-1/(k+1)$ and $g(k)=1$? Remember, infinity is not a natural number.